# App Extension Programming Guide on sharing Core Data context with the main app

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

There is no documentation or sample code explaining if we can share the viewContext with the app extension or not.

AFAK, the app and the extension run in different processes and we should NOT share moc with another process/thread. I should not share the viewContext the containing app is using with the app extension.

So should we create another viewContext to use in app extension(?  but NSPersistentContainer only provides one viewContext)  **or** use a background context in app extension(???)

> While an extension is running, it communicates directly only with the host app. There is no direct communication between a running extension and its containing app; typically, the containing app isn’t even running while its extension is running. In addition, the containing app and the host app don’t communicate at all.

So since they all run in different processes, so maybe (???)  I can come to the conclusion that when the app extension ask for the viewContext, and when the containing app ask for the viewContext, the 2 viewContext(s) are actually distinct instances?

```
class Master {
    static let shared: Master = Master()

    lazy var persistentContainer: CCPersistentContainer = {
        let container = CCPersistentContainer(name: "xt")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    private var _backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        if _backgroundContext == nil {
            _backgroundContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
        }
        return _backgroundContext
    }

    var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    func saveContext() {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---- More On How To Sync Data Across Processes ----

**1. WWDC 15: 224_hd_app_extension_best_practices**

This WWDC session talks about how to post notification x processes.

**2. NSMergePolicy**

A policy object that you use to resolve conflicts between the persistent store and in-memory versions of managed objects.

**3. WWDC 17: 210_hd_whats_new_in_core_data**

**4. UserDefaults(suiteName: AppGroups.primary)!**

Comment: a better way is to use core data history tracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't share `viewContext` between the app and an extension. I don't mean you *shouldn't*, I mean it's actually, literally impossible even if you wanted to do so. An app and its extension are two separate processes. The `viewContext` object is created at run time by a process. There's no way for an app to hand off a variable in memory to a different process on iOS, so there's no possibility of using the same instance in both. You also have two different persistent container objects, again because they're created when the app or extension runs.

These two containers or view contexts might well use the same persistent store file. That's not unusual, and it allows the app and extension to access the same data.

Comment: Thank you! You are a seasoned programmer, aren't you? I have one more question, that is, is it safe that 2 process operating on a same database? Should I use file coordination technique or some kind of lock? (I guess it is safe and core data can handle it out of the box) @tom-harrington

Comment: Another thing is... when **context-did-save** notification is posted because widget is saving, and the widget & containing app both use main-queue-type-context, how do we merge?

Comment: It's safe to have two processes use the same file, but if one of them changes it the other won't be notified. Context save notifications don't go from one process to another one. When you do get one, you merge changes using `mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave:)` on the context object.

Comment: Thank you!! For those who want to know more about how to sync data between widgets and containing app, please see WWDC 16 224_hd_app_extension_best_practices.

Comment: Just a minor correction: App Extension Best Practices was a talk in WWDC 2015, not 2016.

Comment: @JonathanZhan Hi Thanks!  This WWDC session talks about how to post notification x processes. More on how to sync things: See Core Data Merge Policy and WWDC 17 What's new in Core Data.